# "No such file or directory" when the file is there

Tags: bash, xpdf

I'm trying to run XPDF on a linux (probably red hat) OVH shared server.

I've managed to have ftp ssh access and put the 64 bits binaries onto a folder.

The problem is : even though the files are there with the right permissions, if I try running it I'm getting a file not found problem (I'm thinking about a missing link..)

Long story short :

```
myusername@ssh1:~/xpdf$ file pdftotext
pdftotext: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

myusername@ssh1:~/xpdf$ ./pdftotext
-ovh: jurisedi@ssh1:~/xpdf$: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why in the world are you pasting your command prompt at the start of your command line?

Comment: @paxdiablo It is apparent that this is something the user is doing. You can actually see it in the posted snippet: `jurisedi@ssh1:~/xpdf$ jurisedi@ssh1:~/xpdf$ ./pdftotext` I suspect a clumsy copy+paste job.

Comment: @paxdiablo No, it could not be. You can _see_ in the snippet the actual command line entered _before_ the command is executed; you can _see_ what is wrong with that command line.

Comment: Sorry about the failed paste, I'm glad you could figure it out.

Comment: looks like pdftotext is running and returning FILE_NOT_FOUND. What does `ldd pdftotext` show?

Comment: Okay ldd pdftotext returns "not a dynamic executable" =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that there is a problem with one of the library that pdfotext binary linked with. You need to do:

```
$ ldd ./pdftotext
```

to check if the file has some problems with libraries.

If it is not a dynamic executable, it is probably a script. When you try to run the script and get a message "no such file or directory", that can mean that the interpreter specified at the first line of the script is not existent.

Comment: if he only copied the needed libraries into a subdir somewhere, they won't be indexed nor available for linking with anything.  It gets complicated from here...

Comment: @lornix: Arlaud said that `ldd` returns `Okay ldd pdftotext returns "not a dynamic executable"`. That means that the file is probably a shell (or perl/python) script.

Comment: @ArlaudAgbePierre: can you please check the first line of the script? It looks like that the interpreter that specified in the first line is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you give in your question (`-ovh: jurisedi@ssh1:~/xpdf$: No such file or directory`) is certainly wrong, I cannot think of any tool that would search for your shell prompt as an existing file. Please try to execute the `./pdftotext` again and paste the real error message into your question. The current wrong error message is very misleading.

But it is your comment "Okay ldd pdftotext returns "not a dynamic executable"" that actually shows what is happening here: Your kernel does not support 64 bit executables.

You can either try to obtain a 32 bit version of the program you try to run or install a kernel that supports 64 bit on the machine.